# Fill in data elided with "..." in output from pandas.DataFrame.corr()

Tags: python, pandas

When I run a command in Python like

```
import pandas as pd
dt = pd.read_csv("C:/Code/StudentsPerformance.csv")
dt.corr()
```

I get some of the data in the results

```
                            t_gender      ...       writingscore
t_gender                    1.000000      ...           0.301225
t_race                      0.001502      ...           0.165691
t_parentallevelofeducation -0.028383      ...          -0.192338
t_lunch                     0.021372      ...          -0.245769
t_testpreparationcourse          NaN      ...                NaN
mathscore                  -0.167982      ...           0.802642
readingscore                0.244313      ...           0.954598
writingscore                0.301225      ...           1.000000

[8 rows x 8 columns]
```

How can I get the all result data (the things that should be in the "..." ) in the results??

Python is showing only some of the data in the results..

Instead of showing

```
t_gender t_race t_parentallevelofeducation t_lunch t_testpreparationcourse mathscore readingscore writingscore
```

in the columns it only shows

```
t_gender      ...       writingscore
```

I want to display all columns

Comment: "everything" is pretty vague. What do you mean?

Comment: What 'things that should be in the "..." '? There aren't any `"` characters anywhere. You need to add enough **code** to make this an [mcve] so we can help.

Comment: Pandas does `...` because if it had more it wouldn't fit on screen. You could use `MyDataSet.corr().t_race` and it would show all values for each column in vertical order for `t_race`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the printing options:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
```